# Eclipse ADT: Failed to create key, cannot allocate memory

Tags: java, android, eclipse, keystore, android-keystore

I am signing an android application for release through Eclipse ADT. I followed these steps:

- right click on the project -> Export -> Android -> Export Android Application
- I filled the key creation forms
- I then click finish and get the following error:

[image]

Do you know what could cause the problem? How can I fix it?

EDIT:

Operating System: ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if allocating more memory in eclipse might fix your error. I searched google and it seemed like this is a problem others have faced, and there where a few suggestions to fix it. One is this:

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-allocate-more-memory-to-eclipse.html

The other was to set memory in eclipse from 1024 to 1024MB. This had something to do with Android export not being able to understand what the memory size is if the MB is not included.

Comment: Thanks, allocating more memory solved the problem. I had to follow another solution as I am on linux, but it worked.